# Triple Integrals with variables in the denominator

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm having a difficult time understanding how to solve the following.
$$\int_{-5}^5\int_0^{\sqrt{25-x^2}}\int_0^6\frac1{1+x^2+y^2}\,dz\,dy\,dx$$
I get to
$$\int_{-5}^5\int_0^{\sqrt{25-x^2}}\frac6{1+x^2+y^2}\,dy\,dx$$
This is where my integration fails me. The next step I get is
$$\frac{6\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{25-x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
I feel this is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use polar substitution $x=5r\cos t$ and $y=5r\sin t$ for next integral
$$\int_{-5}^5\int_0^{\sqrt{25-x^2}}\frac{6}{1+x^2+y^2}dydx$$

Answer (score 1):

A transformation to polar coordinates gives
$$\int_{-5}^5\int_0^{\sqrt{25-x^2}}\frac6{1+x^2+y^2}\,dy\,dx$$
$$=\int_0^\pi\int_0^5\frac{6r}{1+r^2}\,dr\,d\theta$$
$$=3\int_0^\pi[\log(1+r^2)]_0^5\,d\theta$$
$$=3\int_0^\pi\log26\,d\theta$$
$$=3\pi\log26$$